# An error occurred while executing doInBackground() at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done

Tags: android

I am trying to pick data from an OK Cupid json file but I end up with:

> an error occurred while executing doInBackground()  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done.

Below is the code

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment{
        private static final String URL = "http://www.okcupid.com/matchSample.json";
        private static final String TAG = "MainActivityFragment";
        private Context mContext;
        private GridView mGridView;
        private AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Person>> mAsyncTask;
        private View mRootView;

        public MainActivityFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

            mContext = this.getContext();
            mRootView = rootView;
            mGridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
            //similar to how the real app works on orientation change
            checkConfiguration();
            return rootView;
        }
        private class GetPersonInformation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Person>> {
            @Override
            protected List<Person> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    return getPeople();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("GetPersonInformation", "IOException in doInBackground");
                    //cancel asynctask
                    cancel(true);
                    return null;
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<Person> people) {
                RelativeLayout progressLayout = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
                progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (people != null) {
                    ItemAdapter itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(mContext, R.id.grid_view, people);
                    mGridView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                    mGridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mGridView.setEmptyView(mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onCancelled(List<Person> people) {
                mGridView.setEmptyView(mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

            checkConfiguration();
            //onDestroy() not called when doing configChanges so putting the below here
            AsyncTask.Status status = mAsyncTask.getStatus();
            if (status == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING || status == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
                mAsyncTask.cancel(true);
            }
        }
        public void checkConfiguration() {
            int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                mGridView.setNumColumns(3);
            } else if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                mGridView.setNumColumns(2);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            mAsyncTask = new GetPersonInformation();
            mAsyncTask.execute();
        }
        public List<Person> getPeople() throws IOException {
            ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                // Create a new HTTP connection to download JSON
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
                String result = null;
                int resCode;
                try {
                    java.net.URL url = new URL(URL);
                    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    urlConnection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                    urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);

                    resCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                    if (resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line;
                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            sb.append(line).append("\n");
                        }
                        br.close();
                        result = sb.toString();
                    }
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Malformed URL");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException");
                } finally {
                    if (urlConnection != null) {
                        try {
                            urlConnection.disconnect();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, getResources().getString(R.string.disconnect_error));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (result == null) {
                    mGridView.setEmptyView(mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
                    return null;
                }
                return readJSON(result);
            }
            return null;
        }
        public List<Person> readJSON(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject json = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
                JSONArray jsondataArray = json.getJSONArray("data");
                List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
                int jsondataArrayLength = jsondataArray.length();
                String imageURL = null;
                String city = null;
                String state = null;
                String userName = null;
                int matchPercentage = 0;
                int age = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < jsondataArrayLength; i++) {
                    JSONObject o = jsondataArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    if (o.optJSONObject("location") != null) {
                        JSONObject location = o.getJSONObject("location");
                        if (!location.optString("city_name").equals("")) {
                            city = location.getString("city_name");
                        }
                        if (!location.optString("state_code").equals("")) {
                            state = location.getString("state_code");
                        }
                    }
                    if (o.optInt("match") != 0) {
                        matchPercentage = o.getInt("match");
                    }
                    if (o.optInt("age") != 0) {
                        age = o.getInt("age");
                    }
                    if (!o.optString("username").equals("")) {
                        userName = o.getString("username");
                    }
                    if (o.optJSONObject("photo") != null) {
                        JSONObject photos = o.getJSONObject("photo");
                        if (photos.optJSONObject("thumb_paths") != null) {
                            JSONObject thumbPaths = photos.getJSONObject("thumb_paths");
                            if (!thumbPaths.optString("large").equals("")) {
                                imageURL = thumbPaths.getString("large");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    people.add(new Person(userName, imageURL, age, city, state, matchPercentage));
                    imageURL = null;
                    city = null;
                    state = null;
                    matchPercentage = 0;
                    userName = null;
                    age = 0;
                }
                return people;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The error occurring:

```
02-16 06:55:00.959 7880-7908/com.johnbohne.okcupid E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
                                                                     Process: com.johnbohne.okcupid, PID: 7880
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:325)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:354)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:223)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                      Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6891)
                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1048)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:360)
                                                                         at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:19781)
                                                                         at android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:11478)
                                                                         at android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:8069)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.updateEmptyStatus(AdapterView.java:763)
                                                                         at android.widget.AdapterView.setEmptyView(AdapterView.java:687)
                                                                         at com.johnbohne.okcupid.MainActivityFragment.getPeople(MainActivityFragment.java:154)
                                                                         at com.johnbohne.okcupid.MainActivityFragment$GetPersonInformation.doInBackground(MainActivityFragment.java:63)
                                                                         at com.johnbohne.okcupid.MainActivityFragment$GetPersonInformation.doInBackground(MainActivityFragment.java:59)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                         at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code worked after adding the following oncancelled. Was a display error on onCanceled

```
 RelativeLayout progressLayout = (RelativeLayout) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.progress_layout);
 progressLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are touching GridView from doInBackGround method which is not allowed.

Move below line to onPostExecute

```
mGridView.setEmptyView(mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

Read this official document

1. Threading Rules https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
2. https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

Comment: the line already exists on post execute after the else statement

Answer (score 0):

```
doInBackground(Void... params)
```

run on background thread(worker thread), means that after complete task it return results in onPostExecute() method. If you update any UI elements you should update on Main thread (UI thread) only.

In your code the following line

```
mGridView.setEmptyView(mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));
```

the gridview which is UI element. you should not do on worker thread. You can update on onPostExecute() method, because it run on main thread(UI thread).

Comment: i have two lines of `mGridView.setEmptyView(mRootView.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));`     onpostexecutemethod and oncancelrequest method which one are you referring to?

Comment: if update the results on UI elements then use onPostExecute() method.